# How can I get Logstash-Keystore to find its password?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

For background: I'm attempting to automate steps to provision and create a multitude of Logstash processes within Ansible, but want to ensure the steps and configuration work manually before automating the process.

I have installed Logstash as per Elastic's documentation (its an RPM installation), and have it correctly shipping logs to my ES instance without issue. Elasticsearch and Logstash are both v7.12.0.

Following the [keystore docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/keystore.html), I've created a `/etc/sysconfig/logstash` file and have set the permissions to the file to 0600. I've added the `LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS` key to the file to use as the environment variable sourced by the keystore command on creation and reading of the keystore itself.

Upon running the `sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-keystore --path.settings /etc/logstash create` command, the process spits back the following error:

```
WARNING: The keystore password is not set. 
Please set the environment variable `LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS`.
Failure to do so will result in reduced security.
Continue without password protection on the keystore? [y/N]
```

This should not be the case, as the keystore process should be sourcing my password env var from the aforementioned file. Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected, the file `/etc/sysconfig/logstash` will be read only when you start logstash as a service, not when you run it from command line.

To create the keystore you will need to export the variable with the password first, as explained in the documentation.

```
set +o history
export LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword
set -o history
sudo -E /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-keystore --path.settings /etc/logstash create
```

After that, when you start logstash as a service it will read the variable from the `/etc/sysconfig/logstash` file.

Comment: This makes sense, I only wish the documentation would have reflected that. I'll accept this as the answer once I get a chance to test it!

Answer (score 1):

1 - you should write your password for KEYSTORE itself.

It is under ***config/startup-options***.
E.g. `LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword` (without export)

---

2 - Then you should use the Keystore password to create your keystore file.

```
set +o history
export LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword
set -o history
..logstash/bin/logstash-keystore --path.settings ../logstash create
```

**Note:** logstash-keystore and logstash.keystore are different things. you created the one with dot. It is in config/.. directory where your startup.options is.

History command is to hide your password to be seen. Because if somebody uses "history" to list all the commands used previously, they can see your password.

---

3 - Then you can add your first password into keystore file. You should give your keystore password beforehand.

```
set +o history
export LOGSTASH_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword
set -o history
./bin/logstash-keystore add YOUR_KEY
```

Then it will ask for your VALUE. If you do not give your keystore password, you get an error: `Found a file at....but it's not a valid Logstash keystore`

---

4 - Once you give your password. You can list the content of your keystore file, or remove. Replace "list" with "remove".

```
./bin/logstash-keystore list
```